# imapsync - Authentication failed

Tags: ubuntu, perl, g-suite, imapsync

I've deployed **many** Google Apps accounts and have used imapsync a number of times to migrate accounts to Google Apps.

This time however, no matter what I try imapsync refuses to work claiming my credentials are incorrect - I've checked them time and time again and they are 100% correct.

On Ubuntu 12, built from source, my command is:

`imapsync --host1 myserver.com --user1 user1@server1.com --password1 mypassword1 -ssl1 --host2 imap.gmail.com --user2 user2@googleappsdomain.com --password2 mypassword2 -ssl2 -authmech2 PLAIN`

Full output from the command:

```
get options: [1]
PID is 21316
$RCSfile: imapsync,v $ $Revision: 1.592 $ $Date:
With perl 5.14.2 Mail::IMAPClient  3.35
Command line used:
/usr/bin/imapsync --debug --host1 myserver.com --user1 user1@server1.com --password1 mypassword1 -ssl1 --host2 imap.gmail.com --user2 user2@googleapps.com --password2 mypassword2 -ssl2 -authmech2 PLAIN
Temp directory is /tmp
PID file is /tmp/imapsync.pid
Modules version list:
Mail::IMAPClient     3.35
IO::Socket           1.32
IO::Socket::IP       ?
IO::Socket::INET     1.31
IO::Socket::SSL      1.53
Net::SSLeay          1.42
Digest::MD5          2.51
Digest::HMAC_MD5     1.01
Digest::HMAC_SHA1    1.03
Term::ReadKey        2.30
Authen::NTLM         1.09
File::Spec           3.33
Time::HiRes          1.972101
URI::Escape          3.31
Data::Uniqid         0.12

IMAPClient 3.35
Info: turned ON syncinternaldates, will set the internal dates (arrival dates) on host2 same as host1.
Info: will try to use LOGIN authentication on host1
Info: will try to use PLAIN authentication on host2
Info: imap connexions timeout is 120 seconds
Host1: IMAP server [SERVER1] port [993] user [USER1]
Host2: IMAP server [imap.gmail.com] port [993] user [USER2]
Host1: * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot ready.
Host1: SERVER1 says it has CAPABILITY for AUTHENTICATE LOGIN
Host1: success login on [SERVER1] with user [USER1] auth [LOGIN]
Host2: * OK Gimap ready for requests from MY-VPS 
Host2: imap.gmail.com says it has CAPABILITY for AUTHENTICATE PLAIN
Failure: error login on [imap.gmail.com] with user [USER2] auth [PLAIN]: 2 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
```

I have tried `-authmech2 LOGIN` as well which returns:

```
Host2: imap.gmail.com says it has NO CAPABILITY for AUTHENTICATE LOGIN
Failure: error login on [imap.gmail.com] with user [user2@googleappsdomain.com] auth [LOGIN]: 2 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
```

If anyone can shed some light on this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Perhaps that Google account has 2-factor authentication enabled and imapsync cannot cope with that?

Comment: Janne, unfortunately I checked and can confirm that 2-factor authentication is disabled. Thanks though!

Comment: Is IMAP enabled for that particular account in GMail/GoogleApps? Check from GMail interface by clicking the gear icon, then Settings --> Forwarding and POP/IMAP --> See if IMAP is enabled.

Comment: Janne, it is enabled.

Comment: Can you connect to that particular GoogleApps account with some e-mail client such as Thunderbird?

Comment: Remark: I used imapsync with gmail and worked like charm. Don't worry: it _can_ be done.

Comment: Jane, I tried that and it does work an e-mail client.

Comment: Peter I know! I've used hundreds of times but for some reason it just won't work on this account and I have no idea why!

Comment: So guys, I gave up and ended up using Larch - https://github.com/rgrove/larch - instead. Worked first time with absolutely no problems. Thanks for the all the help! (I know the question doesn't have an answer, what should I do in this case?)

Answer (score 2):

Double check the credentials, so give it a 200% check. Follow the Janne advice of checking the credentials via a standard client like Thunderbird or Outlook or manually (see below).

Take care of quoting issues with special characters in passwords, use single quotes surrounding 'passwords' and users 'values'.

```
imapsync ... --password2 'secret'
```

Other point, --authmech2 PLAIN or --authmech2 LOGIN are useless with Gmail now since imapsync already uses them by default. If the login works with a classical email client then it definitively means it is a character/quoting issue in the values. You can check a manual login with ncat or telnet-ssl like in this example (the client part to type is "a LOGIN ..." then "b LOGOUT"):

```
ncat --ssl -C  imap.gmail.com 993
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 78.196.254.58 q1mb175739668wix
a LOGIN "gilles.lamiral@gmail.com" "secret" 
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST... ESEARCH
a OK gilles.lamiral@gmail.com Gilles Lamiral authenticated (Success)
b LOGOUT
* BYE LOGOUT Requested
b OK 73 good day (Success)
```

Also try to change the password if there are weird characters in it.

Comment: Checked, checked and re-checked. Also works with a normal e-mail client. If none of those authmech's work which one should one use?

Answer (score 2):

After having the same problem, I've switched on "Access for less secure apps" which solved the problem.

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps?pli=1

I had the same error with Larch.

Answer (score 1):

My (working) imapsync setup uses `--authmech2 LOGIN` for the GMail side of the connection. I remember having problems with passing my password on the command line, so I switched to reading the password from a file with: `--passfile2 /path/to/imapsecret2`

My Fedora 20 packaged imapsync reports the following modules:

```
Mail::IMAPClient     3.35
IO::Socket           1.36
IO::Socket::IP       0.30
IO::Socket::INET     1.33
IO::Socket::SSL      1.955
Net::SSLeay          1.55
Digest::MD5          2.53
Digest::HMAC_MD5     1.01
Digest::HMAC_SHA1    1.03
Term::ReadKey        2.30
Authen::NTLM         1.09
File::Spec           3.40
Time::HiRes          1.9726
URI::Escape          3.31
Data::Uniqid         0.12
```

It reports the connection to GMail like so:

```
Host2: imap.googlemail.com says it has NO CAPABILITY for AUTHENTICATE LOGIN
Host2: success login on [imap.googlemail.com] with user [user@googleappsdomain] auth [LOGIN]
```

Comment: Sgaduuw, thanks for tip - I tried it but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Another blocking issue for me was that I had to add the account to migrate to a standard email client (thunderbird). Once I added the account and opened it in thunderbird, imapsync worked.

Answer (score 0):

For those that have NORMAL PASSWORDS here is the proper syntax

```
imapsync --host1 mail.yourname.com --user1 joelawrence@frame-all.com \
  --password1 '$4Password' --ssl1 \
  --host2 mail.vlc3.com --user2 joelawrence@frame-all.com \
  --password2 '$4EPassword' --ssl2
```

The trick is wrapping you password in `''` because we have special chars these days.